# Database Items are not Showing up on Webpage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm working with a ***PHP*** script and connecting via ***PDO*** to a database. The database contains two tables: first one is `required_items` and the other one is `donations`.

`required_items` contains column: `id`, `name`, `required_amount`

`donations` contains column: `id`, `name`, `email`, `donation_amount`, `item_id`

Here's the simple code I'm working with:

```
<?php

    $pageName = "/donations/index.php";
    $databaseHost = "localhost";
    $databaseName = "donations";
    $databaseUser = "root";
    $databasePassword = "pwd";

    //TODO Check, validate, sanitize your input...
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $donation_amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $item_id = $_POST['radioButtons'];

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $databaseHost . ';dbname=' . $databaseName . ';charset=utf8', $databaseUser, $databasePassword);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage(); //TODO better error handling
    }

    // Check to see if someone wants to donate something
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['donate']))
    {
        try {
            //Construct your query with placeholders
            $sql = "INSERT INTO donations (name, email, donation_amount, item_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            //Prepare your query
            $query = $db->prepare($sql);

            //Execute it passing parameters
            $query->execute(array($name, $email, $donation_amount, $item_id));

            echo("Thank you for donating!\n<br>\n<br>");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage(); //TODO better error handling
    }
    }

    $request = "SELECT 
                required_items.id,
                required_items.name, 
                required_items.required_amount - donations.donation_amount AS Amount_Left,
                donations.item_id
                FROM required_items JOIN donations ON donations.item_id=required_items.id";

    $stmt = $db->query($request);
    $item_info = $stmt->fetch();

    // Round negative amounts to zero
    if($item_info['Amount_Left'] < 0){
        $item_info['Amount_Left'] = 0;
        }

?>
    <!--Print out the table tag and header-->
    <form name="donationForm" action="<?php $pageName ?>" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th><th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $item_info['name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php $item_info['Amount_Left'] ?></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radioButtons" value="<?php $item_info['item_id'] ?>"></input></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div><label>Amount</label><input type="number" name="amount"></div>
    <div><label>Email</label><input type="email" name="email"></div>
    <div><label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="donate" value="Donate"></div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Can anyone please help me out with this one? I've included the whole script because I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong. I've tried echoing out the information in the table but it did not work either. Essentially, nothing shows up in the table fields except a *radio button*.

Comment: Don't know about the DB class, but the PHP code is proper. Would just appear that you don't have a name column in required_items, as the error says.

Comment: name might be a reserved word, try required_items.\`name\`

Answer (score 3):

You are aliasing the table, try:

```
SELECT r.name AS Name ... FROM required_items AS r ...
```

PDO::query() returns PDOStatement object, so you need to do:

```
$amount_left = $db->query("SELECT required_items.name AS Name, required_items.required_amount - donations.donation_amount AS Amount_Left 
                        FROM required_items AS r JOIN donations AS d ON d.item_id=r.id")
                        ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ok this seemed to work, but now I'm getting an error "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array" referring to the if statement after "try{"

Comment: $amount_left is PDOStatement object. You can do ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) to get array

Comment: @user2766423 yes, you can't. Because you are using it wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$amount_left = $db->query("SELECT r.name AS Name, r.required_amount - d.donation_amount AS Amount_Left FROM required_items AS r JOIN donations AS d ON d.item_id=r.id");
```

Because you are using `AS` you need to use `r` and `d` for respective tables

Answer (score -1):

**Please** avoid overengineering

```
$sql = "SELECT name, required_amount - donation_amount AS Amount_Left 
        FROM required_items JOIN donations ON item_id=id";
```

would serve you as well

Same goes for all the other code, which is bloated and can be simplified like this

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$data = $stmt->fetch();
if($data['Amount_Left'] < 0) {
    $data['Amount_Left'] = 0;
}
?>
<form name="donationForm"  method="POST">
<fieldset>
<table>
  <tr> 
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$data['name']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['Amount_Left']?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radioButtons" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I do plan on taking all the echo'd HTML out and making it just HTML.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your help in that. I wanted to get it working first, but readability would be much better.

Comment: It is not readability, but rather sensibility. These useless aliases IS the reason for the error.